# configurable map viewer multiple map services

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, configurable-map-viewer

I have multiple map layers (right now about a dozen but that will likely stretch to several dozen) in my CMV. I have introduced several WMS services to operationalLayers that I have published to a local server. Only the "Parcels" service will show up. I have tried different combinations of several layers but I can never get more than one layer to display at a time. Does anybody know why multiple services will not display in my CMV?

This is what the section in my viewer.js looks like:

```
operationalLayers: [{
        type: 'dynamic',
        url: 'http://arcgis.mydomain.com/arcgis/rest/services/Floodplain/Floodplain/MapServer',
        title: '100yr Floodplain',
        options: {
            id: 'Floodplain',
            opacity: 1.0,
            visible: true,
            outFields: ['*']
        },
        identifyLayerInfos: {
            layerIds: [0,1,2,3,4]
        },
        legendLayerInfos: {
            layerInfo: {
                hideLayers: [21]
            }
        },
        type: 'dynamic',
        url: 'http://arcgis.mydomain.com/arcgis/rest/services/Parcels/Parcels/MapServer',
        title: 'NY Parcels',
        options: {
            id: 'Parcels',
            opacity: 1.0,
            visible: true,
            outFields: ['*']
        },
        identifyLayerInfos: {
            layerIds: [0,1,2,3,4]
        },
        legendLayerInfos: {
            layerInfo: {
                hideLayers: [21]
            }
        }
}],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the JSON you posted, it looks you have the configuration for 2 layers in a single operational layer. Since there are duplicate properties such `title` for the single layer, it uses the second one, `Parcels` in this case.

The operational layers is an array that should look like this:

`operationalLayers: [
    {
        type: 'feature',
        /* details of layer 1 */
    },
    {
        type: 'dynamic',
        /* details of layer 2 */
    },
    {
        type: 'dynamic',
        /* details of layer 3 */
    }
    /* keep adding layers... */
]`

In your code, you are missing the ending `},` for layer 1 and the beginning `{` for layer 2. It should look like this:

`operationalLayers: [
    {
        type: 'dynamic',
        url: 'http://arcgis.mydomain.com/arcgis/rest/services/Floodplain/Floodplain/MapServer',
        title: '100yr Floodplain',
        options: {
            id: 'Floodplain',
            opacity: 1.0,
            visible: true,
            outFields: ['*']
        },
        identifyLayerInfos: {
            layerIds: [0,1,2,3,4]
        },
        legendLayerInfos: {
            layerInfo: {
                hideLayers: [21]
            }
        },
    },
    {
        type: 'dynamic',
        url: 'http://arcgis.mydomain.com/arcgis/rest/services/Parcels/Parcels/MapServer',
        title: 'NY Parcels',
        options: {
            id: 'Parcels',
            opacity: 1.0,
            visible: true,
            outFields: ['*']
        },
        identifyLayerInfos: {
            layerIds: [0,1,2,3,4]
        },
        legendLayerInfos: {
            layerInfo: {
                hideLayers: [21]
            }
        }
    }
],`

Comment: no need for that. A second set of eyes is sometimes needed.